# How to show full text for long cell

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm using [SlickGrid](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html). But Slickgrid only shows limited of the text.

How to show full text in every cell ? Is this possible with SlickGrid?

[image: Default SlickGrid shows]

I want to show like this
[image]

Comment: Add your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do that by adding some `width` to the first cell, you've to change two parameters, first change the option `forceFitColumns` to true :

```
{forceFitColumns: true}
```

Then you could specify the width you want for the `Title` cell :

```
{id:"title", name:"Title", field:"field_name", width: width_you_want}
```

**NOTE :** The width of the column `width_you_want` is in pixels you don't have to specify that, add just a number (e.g: 400).

Hope this helps.